# How do you calculate the smallest cycle possible for a given tile shape?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, polygons

If you connect together a bunch of regular hexagons, they neatly fit together (as everyone knows), each tile having six neighbors.  Making a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28discrete_mathematics%29) of the connectivity of these tiles, you can see that there are [cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28graph_theory%29) all over the place.  The smallest cycles in this graph have three nodes.

$f(\text{regular hexagon}) = 3$

[image: hexagon tiles]

If you use regular pentagons, they don't fully tile the plane, but they do still form cycles.  The smallest cycles have 6 nodes.

$f(\text{regular pentagon}) = 6$

[image: pentagon tiles]

If you use regular heptagons, the smallest cycle also seems to require 6 tiles.

$f(\text{regular heptagon}) = 6$

[image: heptagon tiles]

And it's the same with nonagons, 6 tiles to a cycle:

$f(\text{regular nonagon}) = 6$

[image: nonagon tiles]

*Is there a general way to calculate the minimum number of tiles needed to form a cycle?*

$f(\text{polygon}) = ?$

Ideally, I'd love to find a method that worked for any **equilateral non-intersecting polygon**, but even a method that works for any **regular polygon** would be great.

<sup><sub>Sorry for the crudeness of the drawings.</sub></sup>

Comment: How did you make the images?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger, I just drew some polygons in Photoshop.

Comment: Kind of interesting that both of these six-cycles can be broken up by a straight line. [Click here for image.](http://i.imgur.com/3O91PuT.png) It's kind of like you make a line, put two $n$-gons on it, and try to fill it the gap with another $n$-gon, and then reflect across the line. EDIT: Draw the perpendicular bisector of that line for more symmetry

Comment: If that happens for every $n$-gon, we have an upper limit of $6$. (Of course, things can still be lower; $f(\rm regular octagon)=4$, for example due to it just being a truncated square.)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger, that's an ineresting symmetry.  1) I wonder if it continues with higher $n$.  2) I wonder if it applies to non-equiangular polygons.

Comment: There must be an OEIS sequence for this with the terms ...3,6,6,.... appearing in it. All you have to do is to find which one :)

Comment: @user_of_math: Why $3,6,6$? I'd say $a(3)=6,a(4)=4,a(5)=6,a(6)=3,a(7)=6,a(8)=4$. There are [five matches](http://oeis.org/search?q=6%2C4%2C6%2C3%2C6%2C4), but all of them match at rather high indices, so I'd venture that this is not an OEIS sequence (yet). There should be, though, so once we have a solution here…

Comment: Currently [OEIS lists 343 “period 6” sequences](http://oeis.org/search?q="period+6"). So the fact that my answer suggests a periodic solution doesn't mean this shouldn't go into OEIS. But I'd wait for a complete proof first.

Answer (score 4):

I [did some experiments](https://gist.github.com/gagern/e9606b3f12d53ff92c4541e1e7b51d6d) for regular polygons, for up to $n=24$ (click to enlarge):

[image: Cycles of regular polygons]

These experiments suggest that

1. If $6\vert n$ you get a $3$-cycle
2. Else if $2\vert n$ you get a $4$-cycle
3. Else you get a $6$-cycle

That you can get the $3$-cycle for anything that has edges aligned as a hexagon has them is pretty obvious. On the other hand, for reasons of symmetry any arrangement of $3$ regular $n$-gons has to be symmetric under $120°$ rotation, so you have to have those hexagon-aligned edges else it won't work.

It's also easy to see that you can get a $4$-cycle if $4\vert n$, since that's the obvious arrangement for squares. The other $4$-cycles are more tricky. The most systematic (and reasonably symmetric) choice there would be a configuration where two polygons have opposite vertices aligned with one axis, while the other two polygons have an axis perpendicular to the first passing through the centers of two opposite edges. Something like this:

[image: 4 regular 10-gons]

Right now I have no obvious answer as to why you can't get $4$-cycles for odd $n$, nor why $6$-cycles are always possible. Looking at the angles it's easy to see that the length of the cycle has to be even if $n$ is odd, so once the $4$-cycles are ruled out for those cases, the $5$-cycles are out of the question and the $6$-cycles will provide the solution. Perhaps others can build more detailed answers with the help of my pictures.